# Seeing default launcher screen(pink color screen) as a background during activity transition

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm creating an android application for **dual screen** that contains 2 activity splash & home where home activity launch mode declared as singleTask as mentioned below:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/DisableToolbar">

    <style name="FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DisableToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

The splash screen just plays a 10 sec video & moves to the home activity with some transition animation that works well when we launched it in a single screen but by having a 2 different flavor of the same app & launched it in a both the display at a time the video plays nicely in both screen & when it call the home activity , i can see some android default launcher as a background during transition or before calling home activity,how to get rid of this background.
I have tried the following approaches to resolve this issue:

1. Changing the VideoView used to play video in Splash screen to SurfaceView with MediaPlayer
2. Integrated with Asynctask to play video
3. Changed the HomeScreen launching behaviour(removed singleTask)
4. Applied some background theme for splash screen
5. Tried some transition animation from splash screen to home activity,its not invoking when both left & right screen ON simultaneously
6. Finishing the splash activity after giving some delay

Here is the code snippet for splash activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);
        mSurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.splashView);
    }
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setSplashVideo();
}

private void setSplashVideo() {
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.lr_oval_startup);

            if (videoUri != null) {
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this,
                        videoUri, mSurfaceHolder);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mMediaPlayer.start();

                    }
                });

                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        jump();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
           }
    });
}

private void jump() {
    if (isFinishing())
        return;
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class));
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.overlay_in,0);
}


@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i call  jump() directly instead of setSplashVideo() method,i cannot find any pink background from default android launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving theme as FullScreen ie for HomeActivity resolved the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain what does it mean exactly?

Comment: <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen ">